# Download a file from JSP

Tags: java, spring-mvc, download

I'm trying to download a file from JSP, but to no avail.
I created a button that calls a method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "scaricaFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getScaricaFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String nome_file = request.getParameter("nome_file");

    UploadAndDownload downloadFile = new UploadAndDownload();

    downloadFile.download(nome_file, response);
}
```

the download function is

```
public void download(String allegato, HttpServletResponse response){

    try {
            File file = new File(path + allegato);
            response.setContentType("application/download");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            FileCopyUtils.copy(buf, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Errore nel download del file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

But on my chrome page the download does not open. Why?

Comment: Is it working for any other browser?

Comment: @Ayush On Mozilla with Linux, it works.